# Join data on date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables one containing Call Dates and another containing dates when a Tariff was started, i need to find out what tariff a call was made on, on a certain date

[image]

So from the left table you can see calls from number 07710 was on Tariff a and calls from 07713 was on C

I am already joining on where Number = Number i need to add an and on

However i am unable to join on  Calldate = EffectivefromDate as the range is in the same column

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Query so far

```
Select 
a.Number
,a.CallDate
,b.Effectfromdate
,b.Tariff 

From Calls a
inner join taff on a.number = b. number and.....
```

Desired output -

[image]

Comment: Dates are in CYYMMDD formate

Comment: Which database you are using? post your so far prepared query.

Comment: An example of the desired output would be helpful too. The question is a bit too abstract for me.

Comment: Do you mean to filter using a Where clause with a parameter? `WHERE Callate = :someDate`

Comment: Hi @mkRabbani it isnt really clear what database im using, i use a system called Lavastorm which is sort of like a version of SSIS with different nodes to perform actions, i assume its Postgres. Query so far

Thanks

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) so that the values can be copied - screenshots don't allow that. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Hi @johey Desired output added thanks

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson i don't think a where clause would help in this scenario as there are multi numbers on both tables i believe this would have to be done in the join

Comment: Well I asked because the question wasn't clear and I must say it still isn't. Why do you want duplicate rows in your output and why are some tariffs not part of the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it with a correlated subquery:

```
select c.number, c.calldate, t.tariff
from
calls c
inner join tariff t on
    c.number = t.number
    and t.effectiveFromDate = (
        select max(t2.effectiveFromDate)
        from tariff t2
        where t2.effectiveFromDate < c.calldate
        and t2.number = c.number
    )
```

We want the tariff where `effectiveFromDate` is that latest one before the `callDate` (you may want to change `<` to `<=` depending on how the data works).

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a correlated subquery or lateral join:

```
select c.number, c.calldate,
       (select t.tariff
        from tariff t
        where t.number = c.number and 
              t.effectiveFromDate < c.calldate
        order by t2.effectiveFromDate desc
      ) as tariff
from calls c;
```

For performance you want an index on `tariff(number, effectiveFromDate desc)`.

There is no need for an additional `join`.